# Auto encoders Anomaly Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, autoencoder

```
model=AutoEncoder()
early_stopping=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',patience=2,mode='min')
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mae')
history=model.fit(normal_train_data,normal_train_data,epochs=50,
                  batch_size=128,
                  validation_data=(train_data[:,1:],train_data[:,1:]),
                  shuffle=True,
                  callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

The error that is being generated is ->

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 140 and 125 for '{{node mean_absolute_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](auto_encoder/sequential_1/dense_7/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [?,140], [?,125].

Comment: where did you get your `AutoEncoder()` from? And the error explains itself - your input doesn't match the expected input size

Comment: This is clear error, you are using a difference size of input to the model. You need to create a preprocessing function to change your input shape.